# RegisterType with EventAggregator and ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, eventaggregator

I do not understand how we register an `IEventAggregator` instance so we can inject it into a `ViewModel`.

Example:

I define my `MainViewModel`:

```
...
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    ...
}
...
```

Then, I need to somehow register a class that implements `IEventAggregator` that I want to inject in my `ViewModel`.

In my `ModuleInit` class, I would have something like this:

```
...
private IUnityContainer _container;

public ModuleInit(IUnityContainer _container) {
   _container = container;
}
...
public void Initialize() {
   container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, ___(something)___>();
   ...
}
```

In my `MainViewModel` class, I can also implement `_eventAggregator = ServiceLocator,Current.GetInstance<IEventAggregator>();`, but I don't really understand conceptually what I'm doing. The program just works...

I would really like to understand what `ServiceLocator` is actually doing, and what I should be doing to appropriately register a type with my container. I don't define a class the implements `IEventAggregator`, so where is `ServiceLocator` getting the instance? And what would I then have to register so that when I resolve something, like my `ViewModel`, it will create a new `EventAggregator` instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EventAggregator:**

The Prism library has a default `EventAggregator` you can use. 
It is located in `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events` if you use Prism < 5.0 or in `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.PubSubEvents` if you use Prism >= 5.0

Also, if you use the `UnityBootstrapper` from`UnityExtensions`, which i suspect since you are also using modules, then all build in services (Including the `EventAggregator`) in prism will be registered for you:

```
class MyBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        // the base.ConfigureContainer setup all build in prism services
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        //register your own stuff
    }
}
```

**ServiceLocator:**

The `ServiceLocator` is simply a static wrapper, which contacts the current instance of the `IUnityContainer` for a resolve. You should **NEVER** use the `ServiceLocator` to fetch resolves, unless there is no possible way to to it otherwise (e.g. in a static constructor). This pattern is called *The Service Locator Pattern*, and is generally not appreciated.

**UnityContainer:**

The container's job is to create instances of whatever class is registered to a specific interface, monitor their lifetime, and reuse instances if specified. 
So when you register:

```
container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
```

...you simply instruct the container to return an instance of `EventAggregator`, when a class constructor has a parameter of type `IEventAggregator`.

However if you only wish a single instance of the registered class, then you need to specify the lifetime manager: `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`, like so:

```
... , EventAggreagator>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

This instructs the container to reuse the same instance every time is is requested.
The default lifetime manager when using `RegisterType` is the `TransientLifetimeManager` which will instruct the container to create a new instance every time.

Note: If you use the `RegisterInstance` at some point, then note that the default lifetimeManager is the `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`, not the transient.

**Further reading:**

I suggest you read up on *Dependency Injection* and *Inversion of Control*, which is exactly what you are trying to do. Also maybe a tutorial of how prism works.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Since the Bootstrapper's `Run()` method, which implements `UnityBootstrapper` registers the necessary services, shouldn't I just have to call `container.Resolve<MainViewModel>()`, which would inject an instance of `EventAggregator`? At the moment, I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error. That is where my confusion lies.

Comment: Yes that is what should happen. When do you call `Resolve<MainViewModel>()`, maybe it is before the container has been setup?
Try posting the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Called when I initialize the Module. `public void Initialize() { }`

Comment: At that point, the EventAggregator should be setup.. Try `var aggregator = _container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();` if it works, then it is not the aggregator

Comment: Maybe check at what code line the exception occurs, in the exception stacktrace

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I incorrectly set the `DataContext` in my `View` constructor. Is there a way to set the `DataContext` purely in the `.xaml` file, or do I need to hook it up in the codebehind so that Unity can properly inject the needed dependency?

Comment: To clarify, at the moment, I'm setting the `DataContext` with `public void Initialize(IMainViewModel viewModel) : this() { this.DataContext = viewModel }` and then registering/resolving during the `Modules` instantiation (i.e. `_container.RegisterType<IMainViewModel, MainViewModel>(); _container.Resolve<MainView>();`)

Comment: And to clarify further: just declaring the DataContext with: `<viewmodel: MainViewModel/>` (where `viewmodel` is the appropriate namespace), does not work, because Unity can't seem to resolve the dependencies.

Comment: For Unity to be able to inject the ViewModel, then you need to add it to the constructor in code behind.. Xaml injection is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Prism framework has `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Events.EventAggregator` class which implements `IEventAggregator`. Assuming you have implemented your BootStrapper by extending `UnityBootstrapper` which, as I remember, already registers `IEventAggregator`to `EventAggregator` class hence you need not to do it again. 
Resolving `IEventAggregator` using the UnityContainer will give you `EventAggregator` Singleton instance.

Your ServiceLocator internally be calling container.Resolve to get EventAggregator instance, hence it is working for you.